# Lowercase and replace spaces with dashes in MakeFile command for generating blog post filename

Tags: bash, makefile, hugo

I would like to format string from the command line: `make post title='This is a hello world post!'`. The title string should be formatted like: `$(title) | tr ' ' '-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`.

The `MakeFile` create a new Hugo blog entry:

```
post:
    @echo "New post: $(title)"
    hugo new posts/"$(shouldBeFormattedTitle)".md
```

Question is, how can I use the above `tr` commands (or alternative) for `shouldBeFormattedTitle`?

Answer (score 3):

Your substitutions are probably not enough to sanitize any string into a valid file name. But with your own specifications (spaces to hiphens and uppercase to lowercase):

```
post:
    @echo "New post: $(title)"
    shouldBeFormattedTitle=$$(echo "$(title)" | tr ' ' '-' | \
      tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); \
    hugo new posts/"$$shouldBeFormattedTitle".md
```

Demo:

```sh
make post title='This is a hello world post! Date: 2021/11/04'
New post: This is a hello world post! Date: 2021/11/04
hugo new posts/this-is-a-hello-world-post!-date:-2021/11/04.md
```

As you can see, some other characters can be a real problem in a file name. If you really want to sanitize the string (and it does not contain newline characters), you could try:

```
post:
    @echo "New post: $(title)"
    shouldBeFormattedTitle=$$(echo "$(title)" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | \
      tr -c a-z0-9 - | sed 's/--\+/-/g;s/^-\+//;s/-\+$$//'); \
    hugo new posts/"$$shouldBeFormattedTitle".md
```

The `tr -c a-z0-9 -` replaces all non-alpha-numeric characters by `-` and the `sed` command removes the leading, trailing and duplicate `-`. Demo:

```sh
$ make post title='This is a hello world post! Date: 2021/11/04'
New post: This is a hello world post! Date: 2021-11-04
hugo new posts/this-is-a-hello-world-post-date-2021-11-04.md
```

If you use one or the other pay attention to the `$$`, to the chaining of the shell commands with a semi-colon and to the `\` line continuation. They are all needed.

Comment: It seems that the trailing `-` isn't being removed. Example: `make post title="Test"` creates the file `test-.md`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here. `make post title="Test"` creates `posts/test.md`. Anyway, considering the `sed` command `s/-\+$//` (`s/-\+$$//` in the make recipe), I don't see how there could be any trailing `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Character replacement can be done directly using a `Makefile` function, but case modifications may need an external shell command:

```
.PHONY: title
e :=
formatted = $(shell title="$(subst $(e) $(e),-,$(title))"; echo "$${title,,}")
title:
    @echo "$(formatted)"
```

A test:

```
$ make title='S O M E T H I N G' title
s-o-m-e-t-h-i-n-g
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd generate the string using a shell function (unverified):

```
title ?= no_title
new_post := posts/$(shell $(title) | tr ' ' '-' | tr '[:upper:]').md
post: $(new_post)

$(new_post):
    @echo "New post: $(title)"
    hugo new $@
```